# Find dropout rate using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Given a datasett representing edges in a graph I want to find out what the difference is in the number of incoming vs number of outgoing to find out how many dropouts there has been in the node:

```
source    target
1         2
1         3
4         1
4         2
6         1
```

What I have so far is not really giving me what I want, Im sure im missing something.

```
def find_dropout(edge_df):
    # how many outgoing are there from source
    indata = edge_df.groupby('target').count()
    # how many incoming are there to target
    utdata = edge_df.groupby('source').count()
    merged = pd.concat([indata, utdata], axis=1, join='inner')
    merged['dropout'] = (1 - (merged['source'] / merged['target'])) * 100
    return merged['dropout']
```

What am I doint wrong and what is the most ideomatic way in pandas to do what I want?

Comment: What do you want it to return? With your current data it's only going to return one row with the value of 0. Are you sure you want to `count()` instead of `sum()` against your groups?

Comment: I want to count. The numbers are node ids. I want to return onel colum with the percentage that droped out.

Comment: Please post the expected output to help people here. Also add a reproducible code block `df = pd.DataFrame( YOUR DATA)` `to_dict()` might be helpful in this.